# Mui datatables support nested array from API?

Tags: reactjs, api, material-ui, react-table, mui-datatable

I want to use MUI datatable with the following nested array currently working like this as expected:

```
  {this.state.posts.map((posts,index) => (
      <>
      {posts.map((item, j) => (
      <tr key={j}>
        <td>{item.id}</td>
        <td>{item.date}</td>
      </tr>
        )
      )}
      </>
  ))}
```

I have my MUIDatatables set  up with the correct columns:

```
const columns = ["ID", "Date"];

const options = {
  filterType: 'checkbox',
  enableNestedDataAccess: "."
};
```

And then my MUI table component would presumably work as something like this for the data:

```
<MUIDataTable
  title={"Employee List"}
  data={this.state.posts.map((posts,index) => (
    {posts.map((item,j) => {
        return [
            item.id,
            item.date,
        ]
    })}
  ))}
  columns={columns}
  options={options}
/>
```

**But this syntax doesnt seem to be working for the data part (or supported at all?). Any ideas how to achieve this with data coming directly from the API in a nested array or how to approach this for a solution?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that given your source data, you give `MUIDataTable` `data` prop an array with 3 dimensions, instead of 2 expected.

To fix that, you could try to flatten the source arrays to have a normal collection of objects, and then iterate over it.

Example:

```js
<MUIDataTable
  title={"Employee List"}
  data={this.state.posts.flat().map(item => {
        return [
            item.id,
            item.date,
        ]
    })}
  ))}
  columns={columns}
  options={options}
/>
```

Would that work?